# Opinion on this logo made with Adobe Draw

Tags: logo, typography

I've created this logo using my finger on Adobe Draw and fine tuned it a bit on Illustrator.

I like the signature aspect (It says Aria), however as time goes on I'm not sure if the A is out of place or it's not correct to have the A so much larger than the remaining text?

Is there any rules to this style I should have followed? Any other opinions?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the dynamics, I like the proportional relationships, and I like the fluidity. I think the relationship of the "A" to rest is rather nice in fact.

I looked (per user287001's advice to you) briefly through a few pages of google image results, and I can comment that a) Aria as a business or enterprise name is incredibly common, is often accompanied by a typographic logo, most frequently these are using a hand or script feel to the name typography, but also b) I didn't see any in that initial search which would concern me as being close enough for confusion; however c) user287001 is correct that even if it's not a close match, existing groups whose logotype is somewhat close might decide to have a legal field day... perhaps wrapping yours in a badge, capsule or some other manner, possibly allowing the logotype to break bounds, to provide both discrete negative space interactions and provide a unique silhouette woud decrease any risk of that.

I like your starting point - it's reasonably strong from a design standpoint.

Comment: Very kind, thank you. I appreciate the feedback as I can become overly concerned with the idea of proportion.

I've taken on board user287001's comments as well, there are definitely some close comparisons. I hadn't thought to do the Google search - so thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check carefully is an image search with "Aria logo" You'll find the word is already well used in business and some of them have so much resembling logo that their owners can  think to start a money collecting operation - at least, if you happen to live in the same country and be business rivals for each other.